# What Particle/Face means/does?

Tags: particles, system

I'm fallowing a tutorial about Hair. And in the Tutorial, he alters the value of the Particle/Face property in The Particle System but don't explain what it does.

And I'm not noticing any difference visually in the particles.

Can somebody tell me what it does?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the number of Particles **PER** Face, expressed like a ratio.

If you leave it at 0 it emits whatever number of particles per face it wants, based on the total number of particles you defined on the fields above.

If you set it to any other number, then that exact number of particles will be emitted from each face, regardless of how many total particles there are.

Comment: I see. It makes sense now. It's strange because I'd assume if I increased the number in the property the number of particles would increase as well but visually I can't see any difference.